# Is my external Toshiba USB 3.0 hard disk drive dead? Tested on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, usb

Out of nowhere my external Toshiba USB 3.0 hard disk drive drive isn’t working. When I plug it to a Windows machine or Linux I get the sound from the OS when you plug a USB device… But that’s it. Does this means that the hard disk drive is broken for good?

I tried to check the problem and run:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

At linux machine while pluging in the HDD that is the output:

```
Oct  4 01:13:44 kali kernel: [22098.111203] usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 9
Oct  4 01:13:48 kali kernel: [22102.648089] usb 4-3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.781785] usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a007
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.781796] usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.781803] usb 4-3: Product: External USB 3.0
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.781809] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: Toshiba
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.781814] usb 4-3: SerialNumber: 20131007000287F
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.782409] usb-storage 4-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali kernel: [22102.783120] scsi host12: usb-storage 4-3:1.0
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb4/4-3"
Oct  4 01:13:49 kali mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Oct  4 01:13:50 kali kernel: [22103.780958] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Oct  4 01:13:50 kali kernel: [22103.782867] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.786432] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unit Not Ready
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.786437] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.786440] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.791422] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.791425] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.791428] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.792671] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.793668] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.799418] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unit Not Ready
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.799421] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.799424] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.809570] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.809573] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.809576] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
Oct  4 01:13:52 kali kernel: [22105.814481] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: On Windows open up **Disk Management (or something like that)** - What do you see?

Comment: @RACING121 No.. Can't see it under Disk Management .. can't see it under any OS , linux , windows , i also tried few other laptops..

Comment: @JakeGould I have Kali linux V2.0 .. so Debian i guess..any thoughts?

Comment: Also does HD show in **BIOS**

Comment: @RACING121 .. Not really...Can't see nothing

Comment: Have you taken the hard disk out of the USB caddy (SATA-to-USB Bridge) and plugged it directly into your motherboard using a SATA lead and power from your PC? It may not show up in BIOS of you've left it in the caddy/bridge. It may be the USB Bridge is faulty...

Comment: The reason I say that is because your DMESG output doesn't mention the hard disk details, it sees the USB Bridge data from the controller but I'd expect to see data about the hard disk itself - such as make, model and serial number after the bridge had been identified

Comment: @Big ChirsI dont know how to do so...

Comment: Your USB hard disk will have similar internals to this: http://www.techdna.co.uk/product_images/o/257/drx__88211_zoom.jpg - the circuit board is called a bridge and enables the SATA hard disk to be presented as a USB disk to the computer. When your computer installs the bridge it then tries to identify the hard disk connected to it and present this to the computer. If the bridge is malfunctioning and doesn't show the the hard disk then it may be the bridge at fault. Taking away the bridge and plugging the hard disk directly into your computer eliminates the bridge allowing further testing